# Preserve custom node placement of a sankeyNetwork (networkD3) in R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I wish to customise the horizontal and vertical position of nodes in a sankeyNetwork (networkD3) in R, and export the network as a high-resolution image.

I credit and use the reproducible example of CJ Yetman ([enable horizontal movement of nodes in networkD3's sankeyNetwork plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246111/enable-horizontal-movement-of-nodes-in-networkd3s-sankeynetwork-plots)) which allows the user to move the nodes in any horizontal and vertical position:

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

ID <- 0:24
NodeGroup <- c(rep(1,8),2,5,rep(4,7),3,5,6,6,7,7,8,9)
name <- c("29581k","5279k","4218k","1917k","1356k","Ventas diversas: 116",
          "Venta diversa: 97","Venta de: 141","Venta totales: 42705",
          "Contribucion marginal: 18183", "17531k","1744k","1326k","1208k",
          "526k","459k","14k","IIBB: 1714","Costo: 22808",
          "Gastos directos: 6734", "Gastos distribudos: 2958","Resultado: 8851",
          "Total Gastos: 9332","Imp. Gcias: 3098","Resultado Netto: 5.753")      

nodes <- data.frame(ID, name, NodeGroup)
nodes$NodeGroup <- as.character(nodes$NodeGroup)
source <- c(0:7, rep(8,9), 10:16, rep(9,3), 19, 20, 21, 21)
target <- c(rep(8,8), 17, 10:16, 9, rep(18,7), 19:21, rep(22, 2), 23, 24)
value <- c(29581,5279,4218,1917,1356,116,97,141,1714,17531,1744,1326,1208,526,
           459,14,18138,17531,1744,1326,1208,526,459,14,6374,2958,8851,6374,
           2958,3098,5753)
group <- c(1:8, rep(9,8), 10, rep(19,7), rep(18,3), rep(23,2), rep(22,2))
links <- data.frame(source, target, value, group)
links$group <- as.character(links$group)
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links=links, Nodes=nodes, Source='source', Target='target',
                    Value='value', NodeID='name', fontSize=18, 
                    NodeGroup = "NodeGroup",
                    sinksRight = FALSE, 
                    LinkGroup = "group",
                    #nodeWidth = 40,
                    #width=1500, height=500,
                    #margin = list("right"=250),
                    iterations = FALSE)

onRender(sn,
         '
  function(el, x) {
    var sankey = this.sankey;
    var path = sankey.link();
    var nodes = d3.selectAll(".node");
    var link = d3.selectAll(".link")
    var width = el.getBoundingClientRect().width - 40;
    var height = el.getBoundingClientRect().height - 40;

    window.dragmove = function(d) {
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + (
           d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - d.dx, d3.event.x))
            ) + "," + (
            d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
          ) + ")");
      sankey.relayout();
      link.attr("d", path);
    };

    nodes.call(d3.drag()
      .subject(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("start", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
      .on("drag", dragmove));
  }
  '
)
```

[image: PNG image of a sankey plot, customised node positions are lost]

Node positions can be moved in the Viewer window on RStudio, however the resolution is low when using the `Export > Save as Image` option, or when using a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a sankey plot with customised node positions]

I have also tried exporting the sankey plot to html file, in order to customise and export as an  image using the `webshot` package. However, changing the horizontal position of nodes is disabled and the new node positions are not preserved in the image export:

```
saveWidget(sn, "SankeyNetwork.html")

library(webshot)
webshot("SankeyNetwork.html", "sn.png", delay = 0.2)
```

I would be grateful if anyone can suggest a way to export the customised node positions as a high-resolution image and html file. Thank you in advance for your help.